# Chrome extension unit test throws 'unsafe-eval' with Sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-chrome-extension, sinon, sinon-chai

I am unit testing my chrome extension with mocha, chai, and sinon. When I try to stub an object from method I get:

```
EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

at createProxy (js/lib/sinon.js:2488:86)
at Function.create (js/lib/sinon.js:2549:29)
at Function.create (js/lib/sinon.js:3337:42)
at Object.stub (js/lib/sinon.js:3289:32)
at Context.<anonymous> (js/spec/sf-companion.spec.js:44:19)
at Test.Runnable.run (js/lib/mocha.js:4529:15)
at Runner.runTest (js/lib/mocha.js:4974:10)
at js/lib/mocha.js:5057:12
at next (js/lib/mocha.js:4899:14)
at js/lib/mocha.js:4909:7
```

`test-runner.html`:

http://pastebin.com/ij5kD2rY

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `chrome-extension://hjkmpahjllmdacbcennobnfcagfdaife/test/test-runner.html` is a local link to a file on your PC.

Comment: @TomBurris yes, it is. How I can allow this URL? If I package this, I'll have the same url with different extension ID.

Comment: I'd recommend copying the contents of `test-runner.html` and uploading it to http://www.pastebin.com or a similar site, then sharing that link on here.

Comment: @TomBurris Here is the url http://pastebin.com/ij5kD2rY.

Answer (score 1):

> To prevent cross site scripting Google has blocked the eval function.
>
> To solve this add this code to the **manifest.json**
>
> `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"`

by: abhilash

can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242682/unsafe-eval-on-chrome-extension?rq=1)

Comment: But that is if are running extension. But I am unit testing it's resources using the chrome-extension: url and extension resources. How to allow CSP for chrome-extension: url's?

Answer (score 1):

In [using eval in Chrome extensions, safely](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval), the following policy restriction was given:

> script must be moved out-of-line into separate JavaScript files, inline event handlers must be converted to use `addEventListener`, and `eval()` is disabled.

Also noted in the documentation,

> eval is dangerous inside an extension because the code it executes has access to everything in the extension's high-permission environment.

But, since a variety of libraries use `eval()` and eval-like constructs such as new Function() for performance optimization and ease of expression, **sandboxing** was introduced as a safe mechanism to include these libraries in your projects without compromising on security.

So, in creating and using a sandbox, list files in manifest. Each file that ought to be run inside a sandbox must be listed in the extension manifest by adding a sandbox property, which looks like this:

```
{
  ...,
  "sandbox": {
     "pages": ["sandbox.html"]
  },
  ...
}
```

You may go through the given documentation for samples and to understand fully about sandbox.

Additionally, this thread in GitHub - [unsafe-eval security error in chrome extension](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/issues/105) might also help wherein it was mentioned that this was already a fixed issue.